# Return server result to MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService

Tags: android, service, listener

Normally when I have the result of a call to the server, I return to the activity as follows:

```
if(activity instanceof MyClassName){
   try{
         MyClassName mainMenuActivity = (MyClassName)activity;
         mainMenuActivity.DataReceived(new JSONArray(result));
}
```

Now I would like to return but for one

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService{}
```

It is possible? If Yes how?

Comment: What do you mean 'return'?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my mistake, the server return JsonArray and not JsonObject.